# not being able to set the n° of specified threads desired

Tags: openmp

I have this very simple openmp program that is not creating the four desired threads,
    #include 
    #include

```
main () {
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp paralel
   {
       int id = omp_get_thread_num();
       int nt = omp_get_num_threads();
       printf ("I am thread %d of %d threads\n",id,nt);         
   }
```

When I run it the command line says the total it is 1. What am I forgetting?

Comment: which compiler, which version, what are compiler command line options?

Answer (score 0):

If this is really your code

`#pragma omp paralel`

then the spelling mistake you've made will cause the compiler to ignore the directive.  Try this instead

`#pragma omp parallel`

If what you have posted is not really your code why not ?